# Powershell Start-process Java PassThru

Tags: java, powershell

Windows Power shell fails to get the java process details after starting it. It works fine for "notepad" but not for java.

Working notepad cmd :

```
  PS > $apmax=Start-Process notepad "abc.txt" -PassThru
```

Failing java:

```
PS > $apmax=Start-Process java "-jar ApMaxProvMngr-1.0.jar" -PassThru
Start-Process : This command cannot be run completely because the system cannot find all the information 
required.
At line:1 char:8
+ $apmax=Start-Process java "-jar ApMaxProvMngr-1.0.jar" -PassThru
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Am I missing something over here ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use explicit 'ArgumentList' parameter (see [docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849848.aspx));
2. Pass multiple arguments separately.

   ```
   $apmax=Start-Process java -ArgumentList '-jar','ApMaxProvMngr-1.0.jar' -PassThru
   ```

Comment: PS > $apmax=Start-Process java -ArgumentList '-jar','ApMaxProvMngr-1.0.jar' -PassThru
Start-Process : This command cannot be run completely because the system cannot find all the information required.
At line:1 char:8
+ $apmax=Start-Process java -ArgumentList '-jar','ApMaxProvMngr-1.0.jar ...
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand

Comment: Its not working even with "-ArgumentList". The problem seems to be with getting the java process details in PS.  Even, without any args also, I see this problem: PS > $apmax=Start-Process java  -PassThru
Start-Process : This command cannot be run completely because the system cannot find all the information required.

Comment: Does your java command works in cmd console? Did you try to provide absolute path to java.exe? Did you try to use javaw instead of java?

Comment: Yep.. Its working fine. "PS > $apmax=Start-Process java

PS > " .. Problem starts only when I use "PassThru" option

Comment: The last chance I can imagine - the outdated Java version (related to [this issue](http://www.mzan.com/article/29086051-start-process-with-java-exe-fails-after-java-update.shtml))